# Error al instalar es_core_news_sm: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'es_core_news_sm'"

Tags: python, python-import, spacy

Me da el siguiente problema al instalar el paquete es_core_news_sm de spaCy. En el terminal he instalado ya el paquete spaCy de la siguiente manera:

```
conda search -f spacy    
conda install spacy=NEWEST_VERSION
```

Después de esto he probado a instalarlo de la siguiente manera:

python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm

Pero me vuelve a salir un error:

> No module named spacy

Despues en el Notebook lo he implementado de la siguiente manera:

```
import spacy  
from spacy import displacy  
import es_core_news_sm
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'es_core_news_sm'

No sé muy bien cómo instalarlo entonces, ¿alguna solución?

Comment: el error que te sale es diferente. En la segunda parte parece que spacy sí está instalado bien

Comment: Si, por eso no entiendo que no me lo reconozca cuando intento instalar el modulo de español.

Comment: Mmmm pero lo raro es que cuando le digas `python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm` te diga `No module named spacy` y cuando hagas `import space; ....; import es_core_news_sm` te salte el error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'es_core_news_sm'`y no el de `No module spacy`.

Comment: Ya yo tampoco entiendo por qué, porque antes si que me funcionaba así y no entiendo porqué ya no.

Comment: sería bueno empezar de cero, desinstalar paquetes y editar la pregunta con un paso a paso secuencial, ordenado según vas probando. De lo contrario, es expediente x

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como indica la [documentación de Spanish - spaCy](https://spacy.io/models/es), debes bajarte los modelos:

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
```

Comment: Si, eso también lo he hecho y también me daba error. Me decia lo siguiente:
No module named spacy.
Y no lo entiendo porque lo he hecho justo despues de instalarme spaCy

Comment: si eso ya lo probaste, por favor indícalo en tu pregunta dándole a `edit`, así como el error que te da. Recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Ya esta, perdona y muchas gracias